# How to find $u(x,y)$ given $\frac{\partial u}{\partial x}$?

Tags: multivariable-calculus, partial-derivative

[image]

In the third line from the bottom, they find $u$, but I don't understand how they did it, could someone explain in more detail?

Comment: Integrate it over $x$

Comment: Wouldn't that give $u = x^{2}y + \cos y \sin x + c_{1}$?

Comment: This is an exact differential equation. If you find this confusing I suggest going Here. https://www.khanacademy.org/math/differential-equations/first-order-differential-equations/exact-equations/v/exact-equations-intuition-1-proofy

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Partially differentiate the third line from the bottom ($u=\dots$) w.r.t to $x$ and you see that you get the line above it.

The constant $c_1$ is just the usual integration constant (that always disappears when you take the derivative) and $f(y)$, which is some function of $y$ (but not $x$), disappears because it doesn't depend explicitly on $x$, so to the eyes of the partial derivative, it too looks like a constant.

Finally, you have to know that $u=u(x,y)$ and no other variables. If, for instance, $u=u(x,y,z)$, then we would have to add yet another term $u=\dots+f(z)$.

*Edit*: As OP points out, $u=ux^2+\dots\;$ should indeed be $u=yx^2+\dots$

Comment: So then is the $ux^{2}$ a typo? should it be $yx^{2}$?

Comment: @mrnovice Oh wow, I hadn't even noticed that! Yes, that is definitely a typo! No wonder you're confused!

Comment: Ah ok, that was my main source of confusion - thanks for your explanation, I was not aware of the $f(y)$ being a 'constant' as well prior to it.

Comment: @mrnovice No problem! Just remember that $f(y)$ only can be regarded as a constant because you're dealing with the *partial* derivative. Cheers.

Answer (score 2):

**hint**

You integrate according to $x$ . $y$ is like a constant.

for example, if

$$\frac{\partial u}{\partial x}=6x$$then

$$u(x,y)=3x^2+f(y)$$

and if $$\frac{\partial u}{\partial x}=6xy$$ then
$$u(x,y)=3x^2y+f(y)$$

Comment: So does $f(y)$ include the normal constant of integration within it? or must it be stated separately?

Comment: @mrnovice It doesn't matter if it is stated separately or not. But in Salahaman's notation, $f(y)$ does include the constant.